# Http initial load data from local json file, then refreshing data via another call to a different file angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular application with the angular cli. Right now I am using http.get to call a local json file and render the data on initial load. My task is after a certain amount of time of initial load, I am supposed to call data from a different local json file and update the UI to reflect the new data. I am unsure of the best way to approach this. Can someone provide some examples of a data refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` function.

e.g.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   // Load from the other json file
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you want to use a json file that contains a list of cities and you want to reference the city names in a dropdown list, this is how you will go about it.
Since you are using the Angular Cli, that means you are using Webpack so first of all, go to `typings.d.ts` and insert an object like this.

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

The above code will allow you to import your json file in your component.

Now go to your component and import your json file. For example:

```
import * as cities from "./cities.json"
```

Next, you can use this little hack to get the contents of the json file.

```
cities: any = cities
```

Now in your view, you can reference it in let's say an `ngFor`

```
 <select>
   <option *ngFor='let city of cities'>{{city.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file1$ = this.http.get('file1.json');
file2$ = this.http.get('file2.json').delay(1000);


Observable.combineLatest(file1$, file2$)
  .subscribe(([file1, file2]) => { ... })
```

If your json files are only local you can also import them directly. Add `typings.d.ts` file in your project root with:

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Then you can use it in your code:

```
import * as file1 from './file1.json';
```